# Method overriding and variables

Tags: ruby, variables, overriding

```
class ModelES
 def initialize(model_name)
   @elastic_search_uri = $search_server + '/' + model_name.to_s + '/'
 end

 def create(model)
   RestClient.put @elastic_search_uri + model.id.to_s, model.to_json
 end

 def update(model)
   RestClient.delete @elastic_search_uri + model.id.to_s
   RestClient.put @elastic_search_uri + model.id.to_s, model.to_json
 end

 def destroy(model)
   RestClient.delete @elastic_search_uri + model.id.to_s
 end
end

class ES < ModelES
 def initialize
   @elastic_server_uri = $search_server + 'doctors/doctor/'
 end
 def create(es)
   #overriden code
 end

 def update(es)
   #overriden code
 end
end
```

I am trying to call the method `destroy` of the super class `ModelES` in the object of subclass `ES` but the variable `@elastic_search_uri` in the call is the one defined in the super class. What  are the necessary changes that are required so that the method call will access the variables of the sub class?

Comment: Which method of subclass do you want to use `destroy` of superclass in ? `initialize`, `destroy` or elsewhere ? Could you make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misspelling - in `ModelES` you call the variable `@elastic_search_uri`, but in `ES` you call it `@elastic_server_uri`.

Fix that, and everything should work.

You should consider refactoring according to @Niall's answer though, as it is more encapsulated, and helps to avoid misspelling bugs...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super` within your `initialize` method like this:

```
class ES < ModelES
  def initialize
    super("doctors/doctor")
  end
  ...
 end
```